# Add node to the div

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to add new node to the div on click on the button. Operator this must be as the parameter of the function addNode(this)

```
<div id = "files">
    <div>
        <input type="file" name="main_photo">
        <input type="button" value="add" onclick="addNode(this)">
        <input type="button" value="delete" onclick="deleteNode(this)">
    </div>
</div>
<script language="javascript">
    function addNode(this){
        var x = document.getElementById("files");
        var y = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
        var clone = y.cloneNode(true);
        x.appendChild(clone);
    };

</script>
```

Comment: You can't use `this` as an identifier, `this` is a keyword!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a different name when declaring the parameter, since `this` is a keyword.

```
function addNode(elem){
    var x = document.getElementById("files");
    var y = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
    var clone = y.cloneNode(true);
    x.appendChild(clone);
};
```

Also, `y` is a `NodeList` and you need to access the elements in it by indexes which you ain't doing.
Therefore `var clone = y[0].cloneNode(true)`

BTW, you're not using that parameter, are you?